# SAS Options metaserver

Tags: sas, sas-metadata

When I'm trying to connect to my prod metadata server in SAS with the options metaserver when connected to the testserver it doesn't find all libraries and tables.

I am an unrestricted user and uses the code below. It works fine when I'm logged on to prod and connects to prod metadata.

```
options metaserver="prodserver"     
metaport=8561 
metauser="xxxx"              
metapass="xxxx"                                
metarepository="Foundation"              
metaprotocol=BRIDGE;
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Are all the libraries and tables you expect to see defined in Metadata on the "testserver" through Management Console? It may be that these libraries are defined in Prod but not in test.

Comment: Yes they are since I retrieve them when I'm logged on to prod and connect to prod with the options metaserver. But when I'm logged on to test and try to retrieve them, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect successfully to your test server but don't see the libraries / tables you see in Prod, then it is likely that those libraries are not registered in the test environment (ie they don't exist there) or that your user account does not have permission to see them.